# Deploying Java Applet using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, appletviewer

I'm try to get a java website and java applet up and running together. I've setup an eclipse tomcat project and created a java applet, which runs fine in the AppletViewer. However i'm having trouble launching the applet in the browser.

AppletMain.class is missing for the WebContent folder what is the best way to get it to deploy correctly?

Eclipse project:

[image: Eclipse Project]

Applet source file:

[image]

index.jsp

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Applet](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_applet.asp) tag has been depreciated with [Object](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_object.asp) tag according to [W3C specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#edef-OBJECT).

```
<OBJECT 
  classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"
  width="200" height="200">
  <PARAM name="code" value="Applet1.class">
</OBJECT>
```

where

- the `classid` attribute identifies which version of Java Plug-in to use. This instructs Internet Explorer to use the latest installed version of Java Plug-in.

  classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"